# Attach a regular JavaScript variable to Angular 2 model (input)?

Tags: javascript, angular

**My code scenario:**
I have Angular 2 app which has, out of multiple fields, one input field (for lookup), that opens a decade old URL in a popup window (using `window.open()`) to get some lookup data. And it calls back a function from the `window` object of the parent page.

The function is defined in `index.html` page of the Angular 2 application like this:

```
<script>
  function handler(res) {
    var value = res;
  }
</script>
```

**The need:** 
The variable `value` now has to be tied/bound to the input's model named `inputModel`. Is there way by which this can be achieved?

Please Note: I am aware that this is not a good practice of having `<script>` tags, everything has to be component based. But its how I have received the task :-P

Thank you!

Comment: you can't. Only way is to change your code in script tag : `function handler(res) { window.value = res;}`.

Comment: n00dl3: this will not update the model of the input. Changing it to 'window.value' will just make it visible to the window object.

Comment: if you want to be able to access that variable from somewhere, you have to make it global. Period.

Comment: Oh it's possible . Inside your component , just declare handler as const variable and use it .I don't see the problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the value on the window object like this: `window['value'] = res;`

Now, you can access the value of `res` inside your angular components like this `window['value']`

But, the problem now is that this will only work if the `handler` has already been invoked by the time the angular component reads the `value` from the `window` object. Your angular component will not be notified of any subsequent handler calls which update the `value` property in the `window` object.

So, you need a **mechanism for the global handler function to notify your angular component** that the `value` property on your window object has been updated.

Here is one way of communicating with your angular component from outside angular:

1. Inside your angular component's template, create a hidden `input`
2. Attach a `(click)` handler to this.
3. In your global `handler` function, use `document.getElementById('hidden input's id').click()` to simulate a click.
4. Now, the `(click)` handler you created in step 2, which is inside angular's context will get invoked.
5. Now, every time the global `handler` function is invoked, the `(click)` handler within angular's context will be invoked, essentially telling angular to get the updated value from the `window` object.

Here is a [working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6pmtmu4A5Jpmv0XzbtDf?p=preview)

In this plunker, I've attached the global handler function to the `html`'s `onclick` handler which is outside angular's context to simulate your requirement. This click event will be communicated to the angular component using the approach I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks CodeWarrior, this helped a lot.